# Manually clear ASP.NET server cache for a single application/web site?

Tags: asp.net, caching, iis-7

How can I manually clear ASP.NET server cache (IIS 7) on a given application/website, like what can be done in IE to clear browser cache for a given domain?

Comment: Would you be able to mark the answer as a real answer? Thanks :)

Answer (score 50):

Use the following to remove all objects from the cache

```
IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator = HttpContext.Current.Cache.GetEnumerator();

while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove((string)enumerator.Key);

}
```

Also, it is a bit of a sledgehammer option but you can restart the entire application as follows:

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.UnloadAppDomain();
```

Comment: I've never seen that method on httpruntime before

Comment: @Chris Mansic: It's there. I've used it before.  Take a look here at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.unloadappdomain.aspx

Comment: Need to cast enumerator.Key to a string since Remove takes string and all keys are strings

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, and recycling the application pool helped me. All my caches immediately reloaded as I wanted.

Ways of recycling the application pool are [described here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/).

Comment: You should add a path on _How to recycling the Pool_. Anyway, could find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling/)